# Can I use Camerax with MobileNet or Deeplab image segmentation models to do real-time image segmentation from camera?

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow-lite, android-camera2, android-camerax

Sorry for my bad English.
As I have seen on official documentations and other examples, there are used the Luminosity model on Image Analyzer. How can I change it to any image segmentation model? Also, how can I change the example TensorflowLite image segmentation app to real-time image segmentation app?

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#5

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/segmentation/overview

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using CameraX with TFLite:

https://github.com/owahltinez/camerax-tflite